# Why is my code throwing a numpy.ndarray object is not callable error?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pattern-matching, fuzzy-comparison

I'm trying to create a string matching logic between 2 files. My current code looks like this:

```
SourceFile ="PATH to sourcefile.xlsx"
wb1 = pd.read_excel(SourceFile)
d1 = pd.DataFrame(wb1, columns= ['End_Customer_Company_Name'])


InfoFile ="PATH to infofile.xlsx"
wb2 = pd.read_excel(InfoFile)
d2 = pd.DataFrame(wb2, columns= ['STID_NAME'])

df9=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1,orient='index')
df10=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2,orient='index')

df9.columns=['End_Customer_Company_Name']
df10.columns=['STID_Name']

def match(Col1,Col2):
    overall=[]
    for n in Col1:
        result=[(fuzz.partial_ratio(n, n2),n2) 
                for n2 in Col2 if fuzz.partial_ratio(n, n2)>85
               ]
        if len(result):
            result.sort()    
            print('result {}'.format(result))
            print("Best M={}".format(result[-1][1]))
            overall.append(result[-1][1])
        else:
            overall.append(" ")
    return overall

print(match(df9.End_Customer_Company_Name,df10.STID_Name))
```

On executing this code, I'm getting the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-735b8fb2c6d9> in <module>
     10 d2 = pd.DataFrame(wb2, columns= ['STID_NAME'])
     11 
---> 12 df9=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1,orient='index')
     13 df10=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d2,orient='index')
     14 

c:\users\mishruti\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in from_dict(cls, data, orient, dtype, columns)
   1235             if len(data) > 0:
   1236                 # TODO speed up Series case
-> 1237                 if isinstance(list(data.values())[0], (Series, dict)):
   1238                     data = _from_nested_dict(data)
   1239                 else:

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Can someone please point out what I'm getting wrong? Thanks!

Comment: `data.values` is a numpy array.  It is not a function, so shouldn't be followed by `()`.  When we write `foo()` we are 'calling' the function `foo`.  That's what 'callable' means.

Comment: Thanks for responding, @hpaulj. I'm sorry if this is a silly question but I'm new to Python and would really appreciate if you could help me understand where exactly do I need to make this change you suggested.

Comment: Isn't d1 already a dataframe? why are you converting a dataframe into data frame using dataframe.from_dict in line `df9=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1,orient='index')`?

Comment: `data.values()` is a valid expression if `data` is a `dict`.  But not if `data` is a DataFrame.  That means the `d1` argument to `from_dict` should be a dictionary rather than a frame, OR, you shouldn't be using `from_dict` to create `df9`.

Comment: Explain the purpose (and source) of this line: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d1,orient='index')`.  Is that something you came up with based on reading the docs?  Or something you copied from some other source (e.g. a tutorial)?

Comment: Thanks @Ehsan, I figured that out later in the evening!

Comment: @ShrutiMishra You are welcome. Glad it is resolved.